# Wordpress Recent Posts excerpt in sidebar is pulling the page/post excerpt instead of the recent post excerpt

Tags: wordpress

I have a list of Recent Posts in the sidebar of a Wordpress blog. The title and author show up properly, but the excerpt that gets shown is the excerpt of the current page/post not the relevant recent post.

The code:

```
 <?php $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=10&offset=0');
  foreach($myposts as $post) :?>
  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?> <span>by <?php the_author(); ?></span></a> <br /> <?php the_excerpt(); ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any idea why it would be pulling the correct Title/Author, but incorrect excerpt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=10&offset=0');
  foreach($myposts as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post); ?>
  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?> <span>by <?php the_author(); ?></span></a> <br /> <?php the_excerpt(); ?></li>
  <?php endforeach;
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Postdata isn't set up. Those functions pull the global values besides $post (e.g. $ID). `setup_postdata()` sets all the right values. Also, I'd suggest reseting the query after this.